# What is a light but elegant frame for my photos?

Tags: printing, framing

I tried to search but it seems this question has not been asked before. So people who shoot photos generally prefer to frame at least some of their shots.

So what kind of frame is good, elegant but extremely light? The major keywords being elegant and lightweight so that the piece is suitable for very thin walls and yet looks professional.

Comment: If the goal is for it to look professional, it might make sense to talk with a professional framer. The skills involved in framing art are somewhat orthogonal to those involved in photography or painting.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on your style and taste.

Look at paintings at Paris' Louvre museum. Most of them have large, highly decorated frames. Now what about Flickr photos? Most of them have no frames. But some photographers have consistent, stylized frames they add to every photo they publish.

My recommendation would be to keep your photos free of frames at the beginning: it's much easier to make things worse by adding a frame which doesn't look good than to enhance the photo by a frame which actually adds value to a photograph.

Once you're absolutely sure the frame will improve your photo, and other people confirm that the photo is better with the frame than without it, then use one.